# Using the storm hdfs connector

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm

I am running cloudera cdh 4.4 on a VM. 
I am trying to use the storm hdfs connector to write data into hdfs. 
the link: https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-hdfs 
There is a test topology to write data into HDFS, i tried to run the topology using storm (0.9.2) but it doesn't seem to work. 
the link for topology: https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-hdfs/tree/master/src/test/java/org/apache/storm/hdfs/bolt

The topology itself requires two arguments ...
1. it is he fs url 
2. yamli config file , i don't know where it is or if I have to create it.

Anybody know about the steps to follow to run this topology?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the storm hdfs connector to write data into HDFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801495/using-the-storm-hdfs-connector-to-write-data-into-hdfs)

Comment: please do not post multiple post on the same topic

Comment: @Chiron In the previous question i only ask about the specific part of the code. In this question i am asking if anybody has used the storm-hdfs connector test cases or run topologies based on that connector, if so may be they can help me run this thing.